# Hiding navigation bar android

Tags: java, android, fullscreen, navigationbar

How to hide navigation bar in android and also from which android version?

I want to make the app fullscreen. No navigation bar will be shown while the app is running.

Please give me a detail about this..Thanks..

Comment: navigation bar or status bar?

Comment: navigation bar..but i think navigation bar and status bar together will not be shown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar on Android 4.0 and higher using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag. This snippet hides both the navigation bar and the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

You can also check out this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html#40